# Polynomial Pell equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Can someone point me in the right direction?

> Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$ and let $D \in k[x]$ be non-constant. Prove that the ‘polynomial Pell’ equation
>   $$f^2 − Dg^2 = 1,\,\,\,\,f, g ∈ k[x]$$
>   has no solutions with $g \neq 0$ if $\deg(D) > 2 \deg \operatorname{rad}(D) − 2$.

At first I tried using Mason-Stothers, but I failed to find the answer.

Comment: Where rad(D) is...?

Comment: We can write every polynome as a product of irreducible polynomes, say: $f(x) = p_{1}^{n1}(x)*P_{2}^{n2}..$, then $rad(f) = p_1*P_2...$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like an easy consequence of the [Mason–Stothers theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mason%E2%80%93Stothers_theorem).

$\deg f^2=\deg Dg^2\Rightarrow2\deg f=\deg D+2\deg g\Rightarrow\deg D=2\deg f-2\deg g$

$2\deg f<\deg\operatorname{rad}(f^2Dg^2)=\deg\operatorname{rad}(fDg)\le\deg f+\deg\operatorname{rad}(D)+\deg g\Rightarrow\deg D\le2\deg\operatorname{rad}(D)-2$

Comment: Following your deductions I get: $$\deg D=2\deg f-2\deg g<\deg f+\deg \text{rad}(D)+\deg g -2\deg g=\deg \text{rad}(D)+\deg f-\deg g=\deg \text{rad}(D)+\deg D.$$ How do i get the $2\deg\text{rad}D-2$?